# How to fetch new subdirectories in git repository?

Tags: git, repository, updates

The git repository ArduPilot has a new subdirectory in ardupilot/libraries/SITL/examples/, the new directory is JSON.  When I cloned the repository, that directory didn't exist, and is not in my local copy.  What command do I use to update the local repository to match the remote repository?

Here's the local status

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

But, I can see the new directory in the github page.

Comment: Does `origin` point to GitHub or does it point to another upstream repo?

Comment: git remote -v returns "origin  https://github.com/ArduPilot/ardupilot.git".   I'm an infrequent user of git, and forget the basic commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do "git fetch origin", not "git fetch" or "git pull".

Comment: Do you have multiple remotes? Does master have a tracking branch?